# The solution of an ODE is bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t)$ and $g(t)$ continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ such as $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|A(t)|dt < M $ and $\mathbb{R}$ such as $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(t)|dt < M $. Proof that the solution $\phi(t)$ of $x' = A(t)x + g(t)$ is bounded.(Show the valued bounded).

If $\Phi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of the homogeneous equation, we have that the solution $\phi$ is 
$$ \phi(t) =  \Phi (t) C + \Phi (t) \int \Phi^ {-1}  (t) g(t) dt $$

So,

$$| \phi(t) | \leq | \Phi (t)|| C| + |\Phi (t) |\int |\Phi^ {-1}  (t)|| g(t)| dt < | \Phi (t)|| C| + |\Phi (t) | M \int |\Phi^ {-1}  (t)| dt $$

How can I conclude the argument?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take $x(0)=x_0$ and consider first $t\ge 0$. The DE can be equivalently rewritten as the IE
   $$
   x(t)=x_0+\int_0^t g(s)\,ds+\int_0^tA(s)x(s)\,ds
   $$
   which gives the estimation
   $$
   |x(t)|\le \underbrace{|x_0|+\int_0^t |g(s)|\,ds}_{\alpha(t)}+\int_0^t\underbrace{\|A(s)\|}_{\beta(s)}|x(s)|\,ds.
   $$
2. Apply [Grönwall's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions) (Part(b)) to conclude
   $$
   |x(t)|\le\alpha(t)\exp\left(\int_0^t\beta(s)\,ds\right)\le C.
   $$
3. Change $t\to -t$ and do the same.